# Shimano freehub body replacement compatibility

Tags: shimano, compatibility, freehub

I have a cheapish (okay - cheap) Shimano FH-M525-A MTB rear hub (QR, 10-speed).  The freehub body has a fair bit of play so I want to replace it.  There are any number of supposedly-identical replacements available on e.g. Amazon, etc., but I was thinking if there is a compatible one with more engagement points than the pretty-awful 16 I currently have, I might as well get that while at it.  Something similar to a Deore -> XT upgrade for this part.

I see most Shimano MTB hubs now have [either 32 or 36 EP's](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/technologies/component/details/quick-engagement.html#:%7E:text=SHIMANO%27s%20rear%20road%20wheels%20and,16%20notches%20for%20quick%20engagement.), which while not high-end would be a significant improvement on my 16.  The freehub body I have is the `Y3SP98110` (shown [here](https://dassets.shimano.com/content/dam/global/cg1SHICCycling/final/ev/ev/EV-FH-M525-A-3287.pdf) as part of the hub).  After much searching I've been unable to find any data to support confidently selecting a better alternative.  It seems at this granularity of part (rather than e.g. the whole hub) there is not a lot of information going, especially on Shimano's site (as [already](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/46354/shimano-rs505-freehub-body-replacement/46364#46364) [noted](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/83757/shimano-fh-m756-freehub-body-compatibility-can-i-upgrade/83778#83778) here).

Does anyone know a part number for a compatible-but-better freehub body that I can search for?

Comment: Read this thread. https://www.mtbr.com/threads/will-m529-freehub-body-transplant-onto-m525-hub.690422/ . Seems like a M756 will be step up in durability.

Comment: @WarrenBurton - thanks, that's a very helpful thread.

Answer (score 1):

Just to close this off...

At the time I looked into it quite a bit, and as the [AliExpress link](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005004608011484.html) posted by @elad-schitrit implies from the number of options, I found that Shimano has over time made a lot of very-similar freehub bodies (even, it seemed, within 10 speed splined), each with potentially slightly different dimensions.  Eventually I concluded it wasn't worth pursuing further.

The [linked answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/83778/70406) in my original question mentions many of the same concerns.

At some point I'll just get a new wheel with a better hub...

---

So I ended up servicing the freehub body instead, which turned out really well.  No additional POE though.

Here a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X9gIEG1db0s) if you want to go that way.  I also needed to buy [this tool](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B08S386GVX), which wasn't exactly easy to use but did the job.